# net Maui text Editor text cursor issue

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I am developing a simple app using Maui .net but facing some challenge perhaps you can give some advice.

I have a multiline text field of type "Editor" and I have one button. The onclicked event of the button should insert the button label text into the Editor mentioned above (very simple task). Now, the issue is when I use the `myEditor.Text.Insert(myEditor.Text.Length, myButton.Text)` the inserted text inserts fine, but the blinking text cursor moves to the far left of the Editor field, instead of staying at the far right.

I tried working around this issue but manually moving the text cursor using the `myEditor.CursorPosition` but the problem is what if the user decided to manually change text cursor location? then pressing the button would insert at the `myEditor.Text.Length` index, thus ignoring the user's intent to insert the text at a specified index.
I wasn't able to find a method that triggers an event when the text cursor moves inside a text Editor in Maui (so that I can handle it in my own way)

Note: When typing using the Android keyboard, there are no issues at all. but only if inserting text programmatically using  `.Insert(index,string)`

Thanks.

Comment: Does this work: Read CursorPosition, insert text at cursorposition, move cursorposition to original position + inserted text length?

Comment: I think I've tried that, but the cursor moves again quickly to the beginning of the Editor field (I am starting to think that this is a bug since Maui is still in Preview stage). The reason your suggestion doesn't also work is because calling ReadCursorPosition will always return 0 (beginning of editor) meaning insert at will always insert at 0 index. I was actually checking if there was a cursorMovedEvent method but didn't find anything similar

Comment: I agree; sounds like cursor position is bugged. Consider adding an issue at [maui issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Comment: Maui has had a stable release since May 23.  Please make sure that you're running the (latest stable release)[https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases] in VS by going to `Help`->`Check for Updates`.  I also ran into similar issues on the Preview releases.  Also, it would be helpful to post a minimum example (C# + XAML) of the issue, particularly using @ToolmakerSteve's recommendation.

Comment: Hi @James, yes it is on the latest version. Just to note, this buggy behavior only happens when you try to insert into the field programmatically. But if you insert using the keyboard, no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the handler to get the cursor position when you insert the text into the Editor.

1. Declare the control on the android platform:

   ```
   #if ANDROID
   AppCompatEditText nativeEditText;
   #endif
   ```
2. Create the method which can get the control's cursor position for android:

   ```
   void GetCursorPosition ()
   {    
      Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EditorHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
       {
         #if ANDROID
         nativeEditText = handler.PlatformView;
       });
   }
   ```
3. Add code in the button's clicked event:

   ```
   int cursorPosition = 0;
   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       cursorPosition = nativeEditText.SelectionStart; //get the cursor position if user chooses a position by tapping the editor
       string insertText = button.Text;
       if (nativeEditText.IsFocused == true)
       {
           editor.Text = editor.Text.Insert(cursorPosition, insertText);
           editor.CursorPosition = cursorPosition + insertText.Length;
           //set the position at the end of text inserted
       }
       else
       {
           editor.Text = editor.Text.Insert(editor.Text.Length, insertText);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I found after updating to the preview version 17.3.0 Preview 5.0, this whole text cursor behavior got addressed. No it works as expected without any tweak!.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Visual Studio to version 17.3.0 Preview 5.0 fixed the issue without further tweaks. This fix came in parallel with the time I was facing this issue and looking for a fix